# Multiple interrupts on the same EXTI Line STM32

Tags: c, interrupt, stm32, interrupt-handling

Is it possible to get multiple interrupts from te same EXTI line for par example for PA1 and PC1 they are both on EXTI1.

So that by clicking on a button on PA1 a LED go on at PB6, And by clicking on PC1 that a LED toggle on PC0.

Microcontroller ==> STM32F091

That is the code that i use for interrupts from 2 different lines:

```c
//PC1
SYSCFG->EXTICR[0] |= SYSCFG_EXTICR1_EXTI1_PA;
EXTI->IMR = EXTI_IMR_MR1;
EXTI->RTSR = EXTI_RTSR_TR1;
EXTI->FTSR = EXTI_FTSR_TR1; 

//PB0
SYSCFG->EXTICR[0] |= SYSCFG_EXTICR1_EXTI1_PC;
EXTI->IMR |= EXTI_IMR_MR1; 
EXTI->RTSR |= EXTI_RTSR_TR1; 
EXTI->FTSR |= EXTI_FTSR_TR1;

NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI0_1_IRQn);
NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI0_1_IRQn,0);
```

The interrupt Handler:

```c
void EXTI0_1_IRQHandler(void)
{
  // Check line 1 has triggered the IT.
  if ((EXTI->PR & EXTI_PR_PR1) == EXTI_PR_PR1)
  {
    EXTI->PR = EXTI_PR_PR1; // Clear the pending bit.
    GPIOC->ODR ^= 1 << 0;
  }

  // Check line 0 has triggered  the IT.
  if ((EXTI->PR & EXTI_PR_PR0) == EXTI_PR_PR0)
  {
    EXTI->PR = EXTI_PR_PR0; // Clear the pending bit.
    GPIOB->ODR ^= 1 << 6;
  }
}
```

Comment: caveat: I'm not totally familiar with the stm32:  this kind of line: `EXTI->PR = EXTI_PR_PR1; ` is assigning the whole `EXTI>PR` register.  I think you only want to modify one bit.  Suggest: `EXTI->PR |= EXTI_PR_PR1; `

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you can't. Sorry.

Each of the 16 GPIO-driven EXTIs can only be connected to one of the six corresponding pins. For instance, EXTI0 can be connected to PA0, PB0, PC0, PD0, PE0, or PF0, *etc*. Values like `SYSCFG_EXTICR1_EXTI1_PA` are **not** pure bitmasks, and **cannot** be combined.

[image]

For additional details, see section 12.2.5 of [the STM32F0 reference manual](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/DM00031936.pdf).